# Opening windows with similar menu bars though the menu and destroying previous windows using Tkinter

Tags: python, windows, tkinter, menu, destroy

I am trying to create a Tkinter management system with pages that opens through the menu. While opening a page, I want to destroy the previous page and open a new one(all these through the menu buttons) but I am not succeeding. Kindly, can someone help me edit the code? I will appreciate it. I have struggled with the code until I am getting confused.

```
from tkinter import  *

root= Tk()
root.geometry("1200x900")
root.title("Hospital Management System")
root.iconbitmap(r'C:\Users\KEN\electron-api-demos\development\grad.ico')

#=========================functions for switching the windows========

def HR_change():
    HR=Tk()
    HR.geometry("1200x900")
    HR.title("HR")
    HR.grid()
    Schain.destroy()
    root.destroy()

def Schain_change():
    Schain=Tk()
    Schain.geometry("1200x900")
    Schain.title("SUPPLY CHAIN")
    Schain.grid()
    HR.destroy()
    root.destroy()

# menus for the root
menubar= Menu(root)

File=Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
File.add_command(label='Open File')
File.add_command(label='Save')
File.add_command(label='Exit')
menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=File)

Departments=Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
Departments.add_command(label='Human Resource Department',command=HR_change)
Departments.add_command(label='Supply chain Department',command=Schain_change)
menubar.add_cascade(label="Departments", menu=Departments)

Help=Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
Help.add_command(label='About ihms')
Help.add_command(label='Manual')
menubar.add_cascade(label="Help", menu=Help)

Settings=Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
Settings.add_command(label='Log Out')
menubar.add_cascade(label="Settings", menu=Settings)

#configure menu for root
root.config(menu=menubar)
# menus for the HR DPT

menubar= Menu(HR)

File=Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
File.add_command(label='Open File')
File.add_command(label='Save')
File.add_command(label='Exit')
menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=File)

Departments=Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
Departments.add_command(label='Human Resource Department',command=HR_change)
Departments.add_command(label='Supply chain Department',command=Schain_change)
menubar.add_cascade(label="Departments", menu=Departments)

Help=Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
Help.add_command(label='About ihms')
Help.add_command(label='Manual')
menubar.add_cascade(label="Help", menu=Help)

Settings=Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
Settings.add_command(label='Log Out')
menubar.add_cascade(label="Settings", menu=Settings)

#configure menu for root
HR.config(menu=menubar)
# content in HR window pages
name=Label(HR, text="Name")
name.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=2, sticky=W)
nameentry=Entry(HR, width=40)
nameentry.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, pady=20)

Age=Label(HR, text="Age")
Age.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=10, pady=20, sticky=W)
Ageentry=Entry(HR, width=40)
Ageentry.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=10, pady=20)

NatID=Label(HR, text="National ID")
NatID.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=10, pady=2, sticky=W)
NatIDentry=Entry(HR, width=40)
NatIDentry.grid(row=3, column=1, padx=10, pady=20)

Jobpos=Label(HR, text="Job Position")
Jobpos.grid(row=4, column=0, padx=10, pady=20, sticky=W)
Jobposentry=Entry(HR, width=40)
Jobposentry.grid(row=4, column=1, padx=10, pady=20)

name=Label(HR, text="Name")
name.grid(row=1, column=2, padx=10, pady=2, sticky=W)
nameentry=Entry(HR, width=40)
nameentry.grid(row=1, column=3, padx=10, pady=20)

Age=Label(HR, text="Age")
Age.grid(row=2, column=2, padx=10, pady=20, sticky=W)
Ageentry=Entry(HR, width=40)
Ageentry.grid(row=2, column=3, padx=10, pady=20)

NatID=Label(HR, text="National ID")
NatID.grid(row=3, column=2, padx=10, pady=2, sticky=W)
NatIDentry=Entry(frame, width=40)
NatIDentry.grid(row=3, column=3, padx=10, pady=20)

Jobpos=Label(HR, text="Job Position")
Jobpos.grid(row=4, column=2, padx=10, pady=20, sticky=W)
Jobposentry=Entry(HR, width=40)
Jobposentry.grid(row=4, column=3, padx=10, pady=20)

name=Label(HR, text="Name")
name.grid(row=1, column=4, padx=10, pady=2, sticky=W)
nameentry=Entry(HR, width=40)
nameentry.grid(row=1, column=5, padx=10, pady=20)

Age=Label(HR, text="Age")
Age.grid(row=2, column=4, padx=10, pady=20, sticky=W)
Ageentry=Entry(HR, width=40)
Ageentry.grid(row=2, column=5, padx=10, pady=20)

NatID=Label(HR, text="National ID")
NatID.grid(row=3, column=4, padx=10, pady=2, sticky=W)
NatIDentry=Entry(HR, width=40)
NatIDentry.grid(row=3, column=5, padx=10, pady=20)

Jobpos=Label(HR, text="Job Position")
Jobpos.grid(row=4, column=4, padx=10, pady=20, sticky=W)
Jobposentry=Entry(HR, width=40)
Jobposentry.grid(row=4, column=5, padx=10, pady=20)

# content in schain window page

email=Label(Schain, text="email")
email.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=10)

# more frames

# destroy the program
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution

Since you are destroying and creating windows many times here, an object oriented approach will help a lot. Wrap all your menus and content into an `HRWindow` class and an `SchainWindow` class.

HRWindow class:

```py
class HRWindow(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.add_menus()
        self.add_content()

    def add_menus(self):
        # menus for the HR DPT

        menubar = tk.Menu(self)

        File = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
        File.add_command(label='Open File')
        File.add_command(label='Save')
        File.add_command(label='Exit')
        menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=File)

        Departments = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
        Departments.add_command(label='Human Resource Department',command=HR_change)
        Departments.add_command(label='Supply chain Department',command=Schain_change)
        menubar.add_cascade(label="Departments", menu=Departments)

        Help = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
        Help.add_command(label='About ihms')
        Help.add_command(label='Manual')
        menubar.add_cascade(label="Help", menu=Help)

        Settings = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
        Settings.add_command(label='Log Out')
        menubar.add_cascade(label="Settings", menu=Settings)

        #configure menu for root
        self.config(menu=menubar)
    
    def add_content(self):
        # content in self window pages
        name = tk.Label(self, text="Name")
        name.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=2, sticky=W)
        nameentry = tk.Entry(self, width=40)
        nameentry.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, pady=20)

        Age = tk.Label(self, text="Age")
        Age.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=10, pady=20, sticky=W)
        Ageentry = tk.Entry(self, width=40)
        Ageentry.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=10, pady=20)


        NatID = tk.Label(self, text="National ID")
        NatID.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=10, pady=2, sticky=W)
        NatIDentry = tk.Entry(self, width=40)
        NatIDentry.grid(row=3, column=1, padx=10, pady=20)

        Jobpos = tk.Label(self, text="Job Position")
        Jobpos.grid(row=4, column=0, padx=10, pady=20, sticky=W)
        Jobposentry = tk.Entry(self, width=40)
        Jobposentry.grid(row=4, column=1, padx=10, pady=20)


        name = tk.Label(self, text="Name")
        name.grid(row=1, column=2, padx=10, pady=2, sticky=W)
        nameentry = tk.Entry(self, width=40)
        nameentry.grid(row=1, column=3, padx=10, pady=20)

        Age = tk.Label(self, text="Age")
        Age.grid(row=2, column=2, padx=10, pady=20, sticky=W)
        Ageentry = tk.Entry(self, width=40)
        Ageentry.grid(row=2, column=3, padx=10, pady=20)


        NatID = tk.Label(self, text="National ID")
        NatID.grid(row=3, column=2, padx=10, pady=2, sticky=W)
        NatIDentry = tk.Entry(self, width=40)
        NatIDentry.grid(row=3, column=3, padx=10, pady=20)

        Jobpos = tk.Label(self, text="Job Position")
        Jobpos.grid(row=4, column=2, padx=10, pady=20, sticky=W)
        Jobposentry = tk.Entry(self, width=40)
        Jobposentry.grid(row=4, column=3, padx=10, pady=20)

        name = tk.Label(self, text="Name")
        name.grid(row=1, column=4, padx=10, pady=2, sticky=W)
        nameentry = tk.Entry(self, width=40)
        nameentry.grid(row=1, column=5, padx=10, pady=20)

        Age = tk.Label(self, text="Age")
        Age.grid(row=2, column=4, padx=10, pady=20, sticky=W)
        Ageentry = tk.Entry(self, width=40)
        Ageentry.grid(row=2, column=5, padx=10, pady=20)


        NatID = tk.Label(self, text="National ID")
        NatID.grid(row=3, column=4, padx=10, pady=2, sticky=W)
        NatIDentry = tk.Entry(self, width=40)
        NatIDentry.grid(row=3, column=5, padx=10, pady=20)

        Jobpos = tk.Label(self, text="Job Position")
        Jobpos.grid(row=4, column=4, padx=10, pady=20, sticky=W)
        Jobposentry = tk.Entry(self, width=40)
        Jobposentry.grid(row=4, column=5, padx=10, pady=20)
```

SchainWindow class:

```py
class SchainWindow(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.add_content()
    
    def add_content(self):
        email = tk.Label(self, text="email")
        email.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=10)
```

To make sure which all windows are active, you will need to set some flags, and then  add checks for these in your functions

```
schain_active = False
hr_active = False


def HR_change():
    global HR, schain_active, root_active

    HR = HRWindow()
    HR.geometry("1200x900")
    HR.title("HR")
    
    if schain_active:
        Schain.destroy()
        schain_active = False

def Schain_change():
    global Schain, hr_active, root_active

    Schain = SchainWindow()
    Schain.geometry("1200x900")
    Schain.title("SUPPLY CHAIN")
        
    if hr_active:
        HR.destroy()
        hr_active = False
```

### Edit

This may not be a well optimized solution, you might want to try showing/hiding frames instead in my opinion.

Destroying `root` implies destroying your application, you will lose access to other Toplevel windows too, once you destroy root. So in order to do that, you can convert the Toplevel windows into `tk.Tk`. Also create a flag for checking whether the root is visible. Here's how your code would look with all that changes made:

```py
# try not to import globally
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.constants import *

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("1200x900")
root.title("Hospital Management System")

schain_active = False
hr_active = False
root_active = True


# menus for the HR DPT
class HRWindow(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.add_menus()
        self.add_content()

    def add_menus(self):
        # menus for the HR DPT

        menubar = tk.Menu(self)

        File = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
        File.add_command(label='Open File')
        File.add_command(label='Save')
        File.add_command(label='Exit')
        menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=File)

        Departments = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
        Departments.add_command(label='Human Resource Department',command=HR_change)
        Departments.add_command(label='Supply chain Department',command=Schain_change)
        menubar.add_cascade(label="Departments", menu=Departments)

        Help = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
        Help.add_command(label='About ihms')
        Help.add_command(label='Manual')
        menubar.add_cascade(label="Help", menu=Help)

        Settings = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
        Settings.add_command(label='Log Out')
        menubar.add_cascade(label="Settings", menu=Settings)

        #configure menu for root
        self.config(menu=menubar)
    
    def add_content(self):
        # content in self window pages
        name = tk.Label(self, text="Name")
        name.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=2, sticky=W)
        nameentry = tk.Entry(self, width=40)
        nameentry.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, pady=20)

        Age = tk.Label(self, text="Age")
        Age.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=10, pady=20, sticky=W)
        Ageentry = tk.Entry(self, width=40)
        Ageentry.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=10, pady=20)


        NatID = tk.Label(self, text="National ID")
        NatID.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=10, pady=2, sticky=W)
        NatIDentry = tk.Entry(self, width=40)
        NatIDentry.grid(row=3, column=1, padx=10, pady=20)

        Jobpos = tk.Label(self, text="Job Position")
        Jobpos.grid(row=4, column=0, padx=10, pady=20, sticky=W)
        Jobposentry = tk.Entry(self, width=40)
        Jobposentry.grid(row=4, column=1, padx=10, pady=20)


        name = tk.Label(self, text="Name")
        name.grid(row=1, column=2, padx=10, pady=2, sticky=W)
        nameentry = tk.Entry(self, width=40)
        nameentry.grid(row=1, column=3, padx=10, pady=20)

        Age = tk.Label(self, text="Age")
        Age.grid(row=2, column=2, padx=10, pady=20, sticky=W)
        Ageentry = tk.Entry(self, width=40)
        Ageentry.grid(row=2, column=3, padx=10, pady=20)


        NatID = tk.Label(self, text="National ID")
        NatID.grid(row=3, column=2, padx=10, pady=2, sticky=W)
        NatIDentry = tk.Entry(self, width=40)
        NatIDentry.grid(row=3, column=3, padx=10, pady=20)

        Jobpos = tk.Label(self, text="Job Position")
        Jobpos.grid(row=4, column=2, padx=10, pady=20, sticky=W)
        Jobposentry = tk.Entry(self, width=40)
        Jobposentry.grid(row=4, column=3, padx=10, pady=20)

        name = tk.Label(self, text="Name")
        name.grid(row=1, column=4, padx=10, pady=2, sticky=W)
        nameentry = tk.Entry(self, width=40)
        nameentry.grid(row=1, column=5, padx=10, pady=20)

        Age = tk.Label(self, text="Age")
        Age.grid(row=2, column=4, padx=10, pady=20, sticky=W)
        Ageentry = tk.Entry(self, width=40)
        Ageentry.grid(row=2, column=5, padx=10, pady=20)


        NatID = tk.Label(self, text="National ID")
        NatID.grid(row=3, column=4, padx=10, pady=2, sticky=W)
        NatIDentry = tk.Entry(self, width=40)
        NatIDentry.grid(row=3, column=5, padx=10, pady=20)

        Jobpos = tk.Label(self, text="Job Position")
        Jobpos.grid(row=4, column=4, padx=10, pady=20, sticky=W)
        Jobposentry = tk.Entry(self, width=40)
        Jobposentry.grid(row=4, column=5, padx=10, pady=20)

class SchainWindow(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.add_content()
    
    def add_content(self):
        email = tk.Label(self, text="email")
        email.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=10)


def HR_change():
    global HR, schain_active, hr_active, root_active

    HR = HRWindow()
    HR.geometry("1200x900")
    HR.title("HR")
    hr_active = True

    if root_active:
        root.destroy()
        root_active = False
    
    if schain_active:
        Schain.destroy()
        schain_active = False

def Schain_change():
    global Schain, hr_active, schain_active, root_active

    Schain = SchainWindow()
    Schain.geometry("1200x900")
    Schain.title("SUPPLY CHAIN")
    schain_active = True
    
    if root_active:
        root.destroy()
        root_active = False

    if hr_active:
        HR.destroy()
        hr_active = False

# menus for the root
menubar = tk.Menu(root)

File  = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
File.add_command(label='Open File')
File.add_command(label='Save')
File.add_command(label='Exit')
menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=File)

Departments = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
Departments.add_command(label='Human Resource Department',command=HR_change)
Departments.add_command(label='Supply chain Department',command=Schain_change)
menubar.add_cascade(label="Departments", menu=Departments)

Help = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
Help.add_command(label='About ihms')
Help.add_command(label='Manual')
menubar.add_cascade(label="Help", menu=Help)

Settings = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
Settings.add_command(label='Log Out')
menubar.add_cascade(label="Settings", menu=Settings)

#configure menu for root
root.config(menu=menubar)


# content in root window pages
name = tk.Label(root, text="Name")
name.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=2, sticky=W)
nameentry = tk.Entry(root, width=40)
nameentry.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, pady=20)

Age = tk.Label(root, text="Age")
Age.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=10, pady=20, sticky=W)
Ageentry = tk.Entry(root, width=40)
Ageentry.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=10, pady=20)


NatID = tk.Label(root, text="National ID")
NatID.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=10, pady=2, sticky=W)
NatIDentry = tk.Entry(root, width=40)
NatIDentry.grid(row=3, column=1, padx=10, pady=20)

Jobpos = tk.Label(root, text="Job Position")
Jobpos.grid(row=4, column=0, padx=10, pady=20, sticky=W)
Jobposentry = tk.Entry(root, width=40)
Jobposentry.grid(row=4, column=1, padx=10, pady=20)

# destroy the program
root.mainloop()
```

### Complete code

```py
# try not to import globally
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.constants import *

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("1200x900")
root.title("Hospital Management System")

schain_active = False
hr_active = False


# menus for the HR DPT
class HRWindow(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, *args, **kwargs)
        self.master = master

        self.add_menus()
        self.add_content()

    def add_menus(self):
        # menus for the HR DPT

        menubar = tk.Menu(self)

        File = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
        File.add_command(label='Open File')
        File.add_command(label='Save')
        File.add_command(label='Exit')
        menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=File)

        Departments = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
        Departments.add_command(label='Human Resource Department',command=HR_change)
        Departments.add_command(label='Supply chain Department',command=Schain_change)
        menubar.add_cascade(label="Departments", menu=Departments)

        Help = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
        Help.add_command(label='About ihms')
        Help.add_command(label='Manual')
        menubar.add_cascade(label="Help", menu=Help)

        Settings = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
        Settings.add_command(label='Log Out')
        menubar.add_cascade(label="Settings", menu=Settings)

        #configure menu for root
        self.config(menu=menubar)
    
    def add_content(self):
        # content in self window pages
        name = tk.Label(self, text="Name")
        name.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=2, sticky=W)
        nameentry = tk.Entry(self, width=40)
        nameentry.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, pady=20)

        Age = tk.Label(self, text="Age")
        Age.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=10, pady=20, sticky=W)
        Ageentry = tk.Entry(self, width=40)
        Ageentry.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=10, pady=20)


        NatID = tk.Label(self, text="National ID")
        NatID.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=10, pady=2, sticky=W)
        NatIDentry = tk.Entry(self, width=40)
        NatIDentry.grid(row=3, column=1, padx=10, pady=20)

        Jobpos = tk.Label(self, text="Job Position")
        Jobpos.grid(row=4, column=0, padx=10, pady=20, sticky=W)
        Jobposentry = tk.Entry(self, width=40)
        Jobposentry.grid(row=4, column=1, padx=10, pady=20)


        name = tk.Label(self, text="Name")
        name.grid(row=1, column=2, padx=10, pady=2, sticky=W)
        nameentry = tk.Entry(self, width=40)
        nameentry.grid(row=1, column=3, padx=10, pady=20)

        Age = tk.Label(self, text="Age")
        Age.grid(row=2, column=2, padx=10, pady=20, sticky=W)
        Ageentry = tk.Entry(self, width=40)
        Ageentry.grid(row=2, column=3, padx=10, pady=20)


        NatID = tk.Label(self, text="National ID")
        NatID.grid(row=3, column=2, padx=10, pady=2, sticky=W)
        NatIDentry = tk.Entry(self, width=40)
        NatIDentry.grid(row=3, column=3, padx=10, pady=20)

        Jobpos = tk.Label(self, text="Job Position")
        Jobpos.grid(row=4, column=2, padx=10, pady=20, sticky=W)
        Jobposentry = tk.Entry(self, width=40)
        Jobposentry.grid(row=4, column=3, padx=10, pady=20)

        name = tk.Label(self, text="Name")
        name.grid(row=1, column=4, padx=10, pady=2, sticky=W)
        nameentry = tk.Entry(self, width=40)
        nameentry.grid(row=1, column=5, padx=10, pady=20)

        Age = tk.Label(self, text="Age")
        Age.grid(row=2, column=4, padx=10, pady=20, sticky=W)
        Ageentry = tk.Entry(self, width=40)
        Ageentry.grid(row=2, column=5, padx=10, pady=20)


        NatID = tk.Label(self, text="National ID")
        NatID.grid(row=3, column=4, padx=10, pady=2, sticky=W)
        NatIDentry = tk.Entry(self, width=40)
        NatIDentry.grid(row=3, column=5, padx=10, pady=20)

        Jobpos = tk.Label(self, text="Job Position")
        Jobpos.grid(row=4, column=4, padx=10, pady=20, sticky=W)
        Jobposentry = tk.Entry(self, width=40)
        Jobposentry.grid(row=4, column=5, padx=10, pady=20)

class SchainWindow(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, *args, **kwargs)
        self.master  = master

        self.add_content()
    
    def add_content(self):
        email = tk.Label(self, text="email")
        email.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=10)


def HR_change():
    global HR, schain_active

    HR = HRWindow(root)
    HR.geometry("1200x900")
    HR.title("HR")
    
    if schain_active:
        Schain.destroy()
        schain_active = False

def Schain_change():
    global Schain, hr_active

    Schain = SchainWindow(root)
    Schain.geometry("1200x900")
    Schain.title("SUPPLY CHAIN")
    
    if hr_active:
        HR.destroy()
        hr_active = False

# menus for the root
menubar = tk.Menu(root)

File  = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
File.add_command(label='Open File')
File.add_command(label='Save')
File.add_command(label='Exit')
menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=File)

Departments = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
Departments.add_command(label='Human Resource Department',command=HR_change)
Departments.add_command(label='Supply chain Department',command=Schain_change)
menubar.add_cascade(label="Departments", menu=Departments)

Help = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
Help.add_command(label='About ihms')
Help.add_command(label='Manual')
menubar.add_cascade(label="Help", menu=Help)

Settings = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
Settings.add_command(label='Log Out')
menubar.add_cascade(label="Settings", menu=Settings)

#configure menu for root
root.config(menu=menubar)


# content in root window pages
name = tk.Label(root, text="Name")
name.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=2, sticky=W)
nameentry = tk.Entry(root, width=40)
nameentry.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, pady=20)

Age = tk.Label(root, text="Age")
Age.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=10, pady=20, sticky=W)
Ageentry = tk.Entry(root, width=40)
Ageentry.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=10, pady=20)


NatID = tk.Label(root, text="National ID")
NatID.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=10, pady=2, sticky=W)
NatIDentry = tk.Entry(root, width=40)
NatIDentry.grid(row=3, column=1, padx=10, pady=20)

Jobpos = tk.Label(root, text="Job Position")
Jobpos.grid(row=4, column=0, padx=10, pady=20, sticky=W)
Jobposentry = tk.Entry(root, width=40)
Jobposentry.grid(row=4, column=1, padx=10, pady=20)

# destroy the program
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: hello Billy, thank you for this. It is working well. However, can we make it to close previous windows and only open a single window at a time. I will appreciate this.

Comment: @Kadidi Check the answer once again, I have updated it.

Comment: Hi Billy, thank you. However, I can still see that once a window is opened, the previous also still remains open. Did you update? I want a single window to be open at a time while one window opens, the previous windows closes. Kindly confirm. I will appreciate it.

Comment: See the edit section of the answer, It is working as expected.

Comment: Hi Billy, thank you. I have seen. You are indeed a wonderful guy. I have really struggled with this. I am happy!